# Can't install PP/PAR module in perl

Tags: perl, module

I tried all the following ways to install PP via PPM on Windows. But unable to install it.

```
ppm install pp
Error: Installing package 'pp'...
Error: installing package 'pp': Could not locate a PPD file for package pp
```

Kindly someone help to install, I have to create exe file from .pl file.

Comment: 2. cpanm pp
     ! Can't configure the distribution. You probably need to have 'make'. See    \.cpanm\work\1487684373.9888\build.log for details.
     ! Installing the dependencies failed: Installed version (1.007) of PAR is   not in range '1.014', Module 'Module::ScanDeps' is not installed, Module   'Getopt::ArgvFile' is not installed
     ! Bailing out the installation for PAR-Packer-1.036.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveState doesn't come with a sensible build environment, you have to install it:

```
ppm install MinGW
```

Once completed install pp:

```
cpanm pp
```

Or to save your time/sanity use Strawberry Perl over ActiveState, since it comes with a sensible build environment out of the box.

Comment: I've just installed Strawberry (win-64 bit) and I get the exact same error